# Who controls Community User?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Who controls [Community User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) or how can one be a part of Community User?

Is he an automated bot, or moderator, or some group of highly reputed individuals in Stack Overflow?

Can some other person/user get the access to this profile - if yes, then how?

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user

Comment: _Can some other person /user get the access to this profile_ probably the devs at SO

Comment: It's explained in the link you have in your question.

Comment: It may be [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)) - just don't let on we know and it might leave us alone... :p

Comment: username: `community@experts-exchange.com` / password: `1rulez!`

Comment: @JonClements It will only postpone the inevitable: question and answer bans for everyone.

Comment: @JonClements Community User 2: Judgment Day. "I can't be baaack if I was never away"

Answer (score 2):

MSE has a more extensive post on it ([Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)) but the general idea is that Community does automated tasks (some of them automated moderation) and owns things that cannot be owned by anyone else. Things like

- Take ownership of approved anonymous edits or bulk edits (i.e. when [SO switched to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time))
- Close duplicates when the OP agrees and asks for it (most normal users cannot close their own questions as duplicate with only one vote otherwise)
- Specially delete spam and rude questions/answers once they receive enough flags (or have it sustained by a moderator)

Nobody directly controls it.

Comment: I love how the only badge that the community user has is the not a robot badge